# Backup Kubernetes PV/PVC to Local Disk w/o using CSI?

Tags: kubernetes, backup, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I'm looking for to create a local backup for PV/PVC in K8s, then restore. (Not using any CSI)

Have tried VolumeSnapshot in k8s, but it creates a in-cluster backup, and what I need is a local copy, so I can archive it and move around. Also found some 3p tools like Stash/Velero/Kasten, but not sure if any of them fits my target.

Can someone point me to the correct document to look at, or if that's all possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the 3rd party tools mentioned by you should be the best fit, especially Velero because as per [this post](https://www.objectif-libre.com/en/blog/2020/01/10/kubernetes-backup-stateful-apps/):

> Velero is a backup tool not only focused on volumes backups, it also
> allows you to backup all your cluster (pods, services, volumes,…) with
> a sorting system by labels or Kubernetes objects.
>
> Stash is a tool only focused on volume backups.

To get more information on using Velero and its newest features you can visit the [official documentation site](https://velero.io/docs/v1.6/) and [this website](https://devops.cisel.ch/backup-kubernetes-pv-with-velero-the-new-approach).

Comment: Have checked Velero, the doc suggests it only support cloud storage providers. I'm looking for to get local cold backup, and not using cloud storage.